# Unable to install google plugin for eclipse indigo

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I'm setting up eclipse indigo for developing gwt application.  But I can't be continue when I got an error message while adding update site http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 in eclipse. It showed me "could not find http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7". My error was captured and can bee seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mgAr.png.

I have no idea what's wrong. I'm just simply following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7.

I know I can download the plugins separately from https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip. But I have no permission to download it.

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 32bit and jdk 1.6.0_23.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe a proxy is blocking you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I didn't use any proxies.

Comment: im facing the same problem. Guys anyone have any answer? im using windows and my screen shot is here https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Byto7mT_V2AyRmw5M2F6NVhYRms

Answer (score 1):

Please check your proxy entries of eclipse preferences. (window -> preferences -> General -> Network connections )

Comment: Thanks. I checked it. Active provider was chosen as native.But My system didn't use any proxies.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same problem while installing the GWT plugin. I have removed the proxy and tried to install the plugin. For that I have removed the laptop from my network connection and accessing the internet from other device(datacard) and tried...Yes installed successfully.

You can use the same [link](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7) for INDIGO.